# REGEX: split javascript strings - ignore commas in nested strings and object-likes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse some comma separated HTML input string and transform them into javascript arrays but I have a problem splitting complex strings which have commas that need to be preserved.

below is some code to illustrate what I can do and what I would like to do:

```
// what i can do:

'2,5,4'.split(',')   // -> ['2','5','4']

// what I want to do
'2,{"name": [2,3]}' // -> ['2',{"name": [2,3]}]  // comma preserved after '[' and before ']'

' 2,{"key": "value", "key2":"value2" } '  // ->  ['2',{"key": "value", "key2":"value2" }]   // comma preserved after '{' and before '}'
```

In short, I would like to preserve commas in data structures

Comment: In your regular expression, you are going to want to look for a "[,]" pattern. What do you want it to split on then? Also, where is your attempt at a regular expression?

Comment: anyway, your desired output is not a valid array

Comment: Why not use a real JSON parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to split on commas not under curley braces by using negative look ahead to ensure , is not contained in curley braces.

```
,(?![^{}]*\})
```

Demo, https://regex101.com/r/nGmRof/2

Here is a javascript code for demonstrating same.

```js
var str = ['2,5,4','2,{"name": [2,3]}',' 2,{"key": "value", "key2":"value2" } '];
for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    console.log(str[i] + " --> split into following");
    str[i] = str[i].split(/,(?![^{}]*\})/);
    for (j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) { 
        console.log(str[i][j]);
    }
    console.log('\n\n');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to reformat your string to be able to process it with a JSON parser (as @melpomene suggests in comments)

So for example with your posted input, you have to remove all double quotes before opening curly braces and after closing curly braces

```js
var str = ' 2,"{"name": [2,3]}" ' ;
str = "["+str.replace(/\"\{/g,"{").replace(/\}\"/g,"}")+"]";
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```